# form_valid creating new record instead of updating in form_valid

Tags: django, django-views

I have following code where I want to update another table from an updateView. I am using following code however in method - form_valid its ending up creating new records and not updating the record being edited.

```
form.instance = form.save(commit=False)
super(AssetInfoUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I am using get_context_data method to add context data that I can use in form_valid to update the "other table".

Can anyone point me how to update the current record in form_valid or what I am doing wrong? I have included relevant code from my views.py - for what its worth similar approach in Create is working great, but I can't seem to figure out how to get Update to work.

```
class AssetInfoUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = AssetInfo
    context_object_name = 'asset_info'
    success_url = '/asset/list/'
    template_name = 'asset_mgmt/assetinfo_update.html'
    form_class = AssetInfoUpdateForm
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AssetInfoUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        alarm_dispatch_current = AlarmDispatchInfo.objects.filter(asset=self.object)
        alarm_dispatch = AlarmNotificationReceiverInfo.objects.all()
        context['alarm_dispatch_current'] = alarm_dispatch_current
        context['alarm_dispatch'] = alarm_dispatch
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super(AssetInfoUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = AssetInfo.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return obj

    def form_valid(self, form,request):
        clean = form.cleaned_data
        form.instance = form.save(commit=False)
        super(AssetInfoUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
        ....
        ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = AssetInfoUpdateForm(request.POST)
        if( form.is_valid() ):
            return self.form_valid(form,request)
        else:
             return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: You'll need to pass instance while form initialization. e.g. `form = AssetInfoUpdateForm(data=request.POST, instance=instance)`. Here instance would be AssetInfo model instance. You might want to check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert

Comment: You're doing a whole load of unnecessary overriding of methods here. With the exception of `get_context_data`, none of your overridden methods do anything that is not already provided by default. Get rid of `get`, `get_object`, `form_valid` and `post`, and the problem will probably go away.